# How to list and delete directories that are not symbolic links?

Tags: directory, symlink

I see plenty of answers on how to list all symlinks and how to remove all symlinks within a specific directory. However what about vice versa?

How would one go about listing/removing all directories within a directory that are not symlinks?

I know that `rm -R` removes all directories recursively but i want to know how to make it not delete symlinks in the process.

I also know that `ls` lists all directories files and symlinks however i would like to know how i would go about listing only directories that are not symbolic links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way finally.

First, run:

`find . -depth -type d`

to make sure the output looks sane, then:

`sudo find . -depth -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

Sure this does get a bit messy on the console to look through, but ... it works! If anyone can find a better and cleaner way to do this please post it.